# ScrollView keeps in center

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, kivy-language, kivymd

I was trying to show a scrollable text, so I put 3 `MDLabel` in a `MDBoxLayot` and put it in a `ScrollView`. Here is the KV string:

```
KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Toolbar"
    ScrollView:
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            MDLabel:
                text: "title"
                font_size: 27
                size_hint_y: None
            MDLabel:
                text: "description"
                font_size: 20
                size_hint_y: None
            MDLabel:
                text: "text"
                size_hint_y: None
'''
```

When I run it I can't see the title and description, only the text, and when I scroll up, it goes back and I can only see the text again. How do I fix that?

Comment: You set boxlayout and labels size_hint_y as None so there is a no any reference for set sizes. Give height to boxlayout or labels.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the height of the `MDBoxLayout` to `self.minimum_height`, it will take the height of its contents. This will ensure the labels fit correctly inside it.

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title: "Toolbar"
    ScrollView:
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            # sets the height of the BoxLayout to the height of its contents
            height: self.minimum_height
            MDLabel:
                text: "title"
                font_size: 27
                size_hint_y: None
            MDLabel:
                text: "description"
                font_size: 20
                size_hint_y: None
            MDLabel:
                text: "text"
                size_hint_y: None
```